# NameError: global name 'thing' is not defined

Tags: python, scope, while-loop

I don't think there is quite the need for the continued downvoting, I am just trying to learn here!

One.py

```
from two import *

ADooDah = Doodah()
something = Thing(ADooDah)

something.DoThis()
something.DoThat
something.DoAnother
if (something.has_done_stuff() == True)
    self.SomeFunction
```

Two.py

```
class Thing(var):
    def __init__(self, var)
        self.SomeVar = var

    def has_done_stuff(self):
        while True:
            id, newMessage = SomeVar.get_next_message()
            if id == 0:
                return true
            else:
                return false
```

I get...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\One.py", line 9, in <module>
    has_done_stuff = thing.HasDoneStuff()
NameError: global name 'thing' is not defined
```

EDITS: The code was indeed peppered with errors. I was trying to show my situation rather than any real code. Rush typing causes foolish typing. Even I'm not that bad! Well, most of the time ;) .

I hope the edits make it all make more sense and you fine people can stop focusing on the crazy syntax errors and explain a bit more about my scope (I assume) problem. I'm fairly new to Python/IronPython and the rules around implicit types and scoping I am still in the process of learning!

I have solved my problem though. Thanks. It was fairly unrelated to the above as it turns out.

Comment: The traceback is telling you what is wrong: `thing` isn't defined anywhere. There are other problems, so once you fix that you'll get other errors...

Comment: Assignments inside of an if-condition are not allowed: `if (has_done_stuff = thing.HasDoneStuff())`. (Also later: `if id = 0` should probably be `if id == 0`.)

Comment: `if id = 0:` should be `if id == 0:` or simply `if not id:`

Comment: @tigerswithguitars I don't downvote, but let me tell you that if you cook as you code, better is to be not hungry. Your code snippets are peppered with errors and incongruities. I spent 15mn to modify your code to obtain runnable codes. Others have corrected. I add that ``if id==0: return True else return False`` can be replaced by only ``return id==0``

Comment: Wow... -4. That is really bad. I am sorry. I should have proof read a bit better! Sorry it took me a minute to look at, I got called away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give the following codes.

I don't know for what they will be usable...... But they CAN run.

.

**two.py**

```
from time import time

class Thing():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.SomeVar = enumerate(var)

    def HasDoneStuff(self):
        while True:
            id, newMessage = self.SomeVar.next()
            print newMessage
            print 'id==',id
            return id == 0

    def DoThis(self):
        print "DoThis' result"

    def DoThat(self):
        print 'DoingThat ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;'

    def DoAnother(self):
        print 'DoAnother time',time()

    def SomeFunction(self):
        print 'Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall'
```

.

**one.py**

```
from two import *


def Doodah(ss):
    return ss.split()

ADooDah = Doodah('once upon a time')

Something = Thing(ADooDah)


Something.DoThis()
Something.DoThat()
Something.DoAnother()

print '\n==========================\n'

while True:
    try:
        if Something.HasDoneStuff():
            Something.SomeFunction()
        print '---------------'
    except StopIteration:
        print "That's all folks"
        break
```

Comment: Yes, thankyou you are correct. My problem in my real code came I think from the scoping and variable declarations I was using. My actual code (rather than the example above) passed an object with the same name as a local object from a different namespace. I think as it was an object from an imported .Net class using IronPython, that uses reflection a lot, it got confused maybe?

Comment: @tigerswithguitars errrr... I don't understand all you explain. Thank you for the upvote. You are fair. I didn't imagine that my answer could be so much useful to you that you accept it. I hope it really helped you.

Answer (score 3):

```
Something = Thing(ADooDah)

thing.DoThis()
```

Your `thing` is called `Something`.
Also, your class `Thing` has none of the methods you are calling/not calling (missing parens). This is pretty much non-sense code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues:

You claim `Thing` is defined in `Two.py`. If so, you need to import it thus:

```
from Two import Thing
```

or (not recommended):

```
from Two import *
```

Next, you need `class`, not `Class`.

Next, you need to define `thing`, which you haven't done. I will take a wild guess that you want `thing` to be a `Thing` object:

```
thing = Thing(ADooDah)
```

then there is the pfoblem with the `if` inside `HasDoneStuff` that someone has referred to in a comment, and the fact that `Thing` is incomplete (also mentioned in another answer).

Comment: @uanchopanza +1 for the patience

Comment: You are right. I have been a bit naughty about my implicit and wide ranging imports. It's a bit of a dirty habit of mine when I know what is in the module... Does this not only import all classes? Are there other attribute associated with * type imports?

Comment: By default, it imports everything in the module. You can control that by defining which symbols you want to export from a module in a sequence defined by `__all__`. I think it is better to import each symbol explcitly, or import the module to keep the namespace (for example, `import Two` and then use `Two.Thing`.

Comment: That syntax is one that is a bit more familiar. Thanks @juanchopanza. It's nice to know that someone at least is trying to be helpful.